# how to keep adding to JS variable?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to continuously add to a js variable every time a user enters a value into a box.

So far if they enter '21' the alert will say 'your balance is £12' but then if I enter '15' I want it to say your balance is '27' but instead it says '15' or rather just the latest amount.

The code below:

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="number" value="" id="amountDropped">
  <input type="submit" value="Deposit amount" onclick="depositedFunds()">
</form>

var firstAmount = 0;    
function depositedFunds(){

    var ad = document.getElementById("amountDropped");

    firstAmount = +firstAmount + +ad.value;
    alert ("Your balance is £" + firstAmount);
};
```

thanks

Comment: `firstAmount += ad.value;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function which makes the change is attached to a **submit** button.

When the user clicks the button:

1. The JS runs
2. The value is updated
3. The value is alerted
4. The form is submitted
5. A new page loads
6. The new page has `var firstAmount = 0;` in it

You should:

- Set the default value dynamically with server side code. See [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) *and*
- Prevent the default behaviour of the submit button

Using an onclick attribute, you need to return false from the event handler function:

```
onclick="depositedFunds(); return false;"
```

Modern code would separate concerns and not tie things so tightly to a specific means of triggering the form submission.

```js
var firstAmount = 0;

function depositedFunds(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var ad = document.getElementById("amountDropped");
  firstAmount = +firstAmount + +ad.value;
  alert("Your balance is £" + firstAmount);
};

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', depositedFunds);
```

```html
<form method="get">
  <input type="number" id="amountDropped">
  <input type="submit" value="Deposit amount">
</form>
```

Comment: very helpful thanks. just wondering how would you keep the variable in session? your method works but if i close the browser/log out etc it will reset it to 0...

Comment: I wouldn't keep it in a session. If I needed to preserve it between sessions then I'd store it in a database on the server and associate it with a session on demand using auth/authz.